# OAuth 2.0 and Open Id Connect claims issue

Tags: c#, oauth, openid, claims

I'm learning `OAuth 2.0` and `Open Id Connect` and now I have a problem: there are not claims presented in `id_token`:

I have created `InMemoryUser` and claims for him:

```
return new List<InMemoryUser>()
{
    new InMemoryUser()
    {
        Username = "SomeName",
        Password = "SomePassword",
        Subject = "b05d3546-6ca8-4d32-b95c-77e94d705ddf",
        Claims = new Claim[]
        {
            new Claim(IdentityServer3.Core.Constants.ClaimTypes.GivenName, "MyGivenName"),
            new Claim(IdentityServer3.Core.Constants.ClaimTypes.FamilyName, "MyFamilyName"),

         }
     }
}
```

My scopes:

```
return new List<Scope>()
{
    StandardScopes.OpenId,
    StandardScopes.Profile,

    new Scope()
    {
        Name = "somename",
        DisplayName = "some display name",
        Description = "some description",
        Type = ScopeType.Resource
    }
};
```

Also, I have created MVC Client and `Startup` class and included profile `scope`:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
    {
        AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
    });

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions()
    {
        ClientId = "TripsHybrid",
        Authority = Constants.Constants.TripsSts,
        RedirectUri = Constants.Constants.TripsMvc,
        SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
        ResponseType = "code id_token token",
        Scope = "openid profile", // "profile" scope inсluded
    }
}
```

But when I obtain `id_token` and decode it, there are not claims which I have set while creating my `InMemoryUser`. Also, there aren't claims in `User.Identity.Claims` after printing them to `Debug`:

```
if (this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Claims:");
    var identity = this.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
    foreach (var claim in identity.Claims)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(claim.Type + " - " + claim.Value);
    }
}
```

Please, help me to find the reason and add claims in `id_token`. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have found the problem solution.

The problem was in `IdentityServer3` NuGet package versions. In tutorial it was used package `IdentityServer3 2.0.1`, but I have installed the package `IdentityServer3 2.5.0`.

I have changed my code when I get scopes:

```
public static IEnumerable<Scope> Get()
{
    Scope profileScope = StandardScopes.Profile;
    profileScope.IncludeAllClaimsForUser = true; // set this property to true

    return new List<Scope>()
    {
        StandardScopes.OpenId,
        profileScope,

        new Scope()
        {
            Name = "somename",
            DisplayName = "some display name",
            Description = "some description",
            Type = ScopeType.Resource
        }
    };
}
```

I have set the `IncludeAllClaimsForUser = true` and now all claims are present in identity token (`id_token`) and I can get all claims in my MVC client using this code (the same as previous):

```
if (this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Claims:");
    var identity = this.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
    foreach (var claim in identity.Claims)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(claim.Type + " - " + claim.Value);
    }
}
```

When I tried to use the older package the code in my question worked as expected (without any changes).

It seems that the default value of this property was changed to `false` in some newer version of `IdentityServer3`.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Every thing sames ok for me but some times the claims didn't mapping correctly due to the diffrence between claims in identityserver and aspNetIdentity

Try to clear the default claims mapping in your MVC app Startup.cs:

```
 // Clear The InboundClaimTypeMap
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
```

Comment: It didn't help. No claims in identity token